# Certificate Policies & Certificate Practice Statements - Destroying Vs. Archiving CA's Private Keys (HSMs)

Tags: certificate-authority

**Please Consider**: English is my second language.

---

### **Background**

I have been looking at different CP/CPS on the web. They all seem to roughly follow the same practices. However, two different policies differed: the first makes sense to me; the second… well, not so much.

Although I can have a vague idea on the rationale behind the second policy, I would like to really understand the different implications of each in order to make an informed decision as to how I would implement this.

### **Contrast**

The first policy (the one that makes sense to me) is from [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/security/pki/policies/Certificate_Policy_-_Cisco_Root_CA_2048_v1.0.doc). On page 22, section *6.2.9  Method of Destroying Private Key*:

> Upon expiration or revocation of a certificate, or other termination
>   of use of a private key for creating signatures, all copies of the
>   private key shall be securely destroyed.

The second policy, requires the private key not to be destroyed, but archived. It is from [StartCom Ltd](https://www.startssl.com/policy.pdf), on page 34’s second paragraph:

> […] CA private keys shall be archived after expiration of the public
>   key according to the same procedure as the CA root key.

### **Question**

My question is then: what would be rationale behind each, and what would be the possible implications of choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling on this would be whether or not there should be recoverable access to archived, encrypted traffic or not.

Policy #1 (Destroying all copies of the private key) from Cisco is attempting to:

- Prevent the old certificate / private key being stolen and used for some kind of spoofing / nefarious activity (even after expiration some things can be done)
- Prevent an attacker from being able to gather a large amount of encrypted traffic over a period of time, then steal the archived private key at some point and decrypt old traffic

I'm not sure what benefit policy #2 would give besides allowing you to recover raw encrypted traffic at some later point if you needed to, after you've rotated the certs out.

Comment: But Diffie-Hellman key exchange provides *perfect forward secrecy* so that even if a TLS certificate private key is stolen in the future, it cannot be used to decrypt saved encrypted traffic.